# Not showing Linux PC's in Network List

Tags: networking, samba

I have Ubuntu Precise and my brother has Windows 7, as well as my sister having windows 7 too. I can see them in the network list, they can see each other in the list, however they are not able to see me. Why is this so? I need this function to be able to operate because we use file sharing functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for file sharing to work in Ubuntu, you need to share something first. The easy way to do that is right click a folder you want shared, select 'Sharing Options' and mark the 'Share this folder' box. You should then see a massage requesting the permission to install the sharing service (aka Samba), proceed as requested, and, hopefully, before long, you'll be able "to operate" just fine.

Answer (score 0):

mikewhatever is correct in that you should make sure Samba is installed.  Each Samba share can be defined to have its own setting to be "browseable."  You can create your share using a Samba GUI or by modifying your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file directly:

```
gksu gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

If your share has already been created, it should be at the bottom of the file.

```
[myShareName]
path = /some/directory
browsable = yes
```

Once you are finished with your changes to the `smb.conf` file, restart Samba.

```
sudo restart smbd
sudo restart nmbd
```

Here's a link to the official documentation on installing Samba and configuring shares: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html.

Note that the simple example I have shown has absolutely **no** security set.  Please check the link to the documentation for more information on properly setting the security.